# How to overwrite the User-Agent Client Hints in puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer, user-agent

I am facing an issue with dealing with the user-agent-client-hints. If you have no idea what User-agent-client-hints are then think of them as some request headers. (See the image below)
[image]

I tried to overwrite the request headers with the code below but it does not work

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true)
await page.on('request', (req) => {
    const headers = req.headers()
    headers['sec-ch-ua'] = 'some thing new'
    req.continue({
        headers
    })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set in `page.setUserAgent`'s second argument `navigator.userAgentData` and associated `Sec-CH-UA`* headers.

`page.setUserAgent(userAgent[, userAgentMetadata])`

- `userAgent` <[string]> Specific user agent to use in this page
- `userAgentMetadata` <[Object]> Optional user agent data to use in this page. Any
  values not provided will use the client's default.

  - `brands` <[Array]<[Object]>> Optional brand information

    - `brand` <[string]> Browser or client brand name.
    - `version` <[string]> Browser or client major version.
  - `fullVersion` <[string]> Optional browser or client full version.
  - `platform` <[string]> Operating system name.
  - `platformVersion` <[string]> Operating system version.
  - `architecture` <[string]> CPU architecture.
  - `model` <[string]> Device model.
  - `mobile` <[boolean]> Indicate if this is a mobile device.

Example:

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setUserAgent('MyBrowser', {
  architecture: 'My1',
  mobile: false,
  model: 'Mybook',
  platform: 'MyOS',
  platformVersion: '3.1',
});
```

Docs: https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.setuseragent (but you will find more info in this Github commit: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/pull/7378/files)

Comment: thanks man, that helped me a lot. for any one who wanna fill these information using a User Agent string I suggest to try PLATFORM.JS